# Permission Management list for SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow

I want to create Permission Management list, I want to have an easy way to request access to the SharePoint site and to manage users.
I want user to fill the form and request their respective managers for the approval. Form should have name, email, role drop down, permission group drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need some kind of customization.

- create a request access form( infopath) then associate a workflow, also store the required information into the List.

You can also think about using the [OOTB Site access request](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/site-access-request-and-invitations-in-sharepoint-2013/). Check the last bullet on the linked blog.

You can also try the 3rd party tools for better result. i.e. http://lightningtools.com/products/deliverpoint-2013/